# Check if password never expired from code is not working on specific network

Tags: c#, active-directory

I got some code of a tool which does many security checks on client machines and I'm trying to understand some bug and solve it - need your help.

There is a test which checks if the user password is set to "never expire". I tried this test offline and in 3 different networks and it seems to be working. There is some WIFI guest network in my company which return exception while executing the code.
Here is the exception I'm getting:

`The network path was not found.
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_NativeObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.InvokeGet(String propertyName)
   at Intel.HostCheck.Engine.Checks.PasswordAge.CheckPasswordNeverExpired()`

See the the following code for understanding the test implementation:

```
    private CheckResult CheckPasswordNeverExpired()
            {
                try
                {
                    DirectoryEntry de;
                    Logger.Debug("Password Age: isCurrentUserLocalUser - " + HelpFunction.isCurrentUserLocalUser());

                    if (HelpFunction.isCurrentUserLocalUser())
                        de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + "/" + Environment.UserName);
                    else de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.UserDomainName + "/" + Environment.UserName);

                    object currentUser = de.InvokeGet("UserFlags");


                    if (currentUser != null)
                    {
                        Logger.Debug("PasswordAge: " + currentUser);
                        Logger.Debug("PasswordAge: " + Convert.ToBoolean((int)currentUser & UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD).ToString());
                    }

                    if (Convert.ToBoolean((int)currentUser & UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD))
                    {
                        Logger.Debug("Password Age: check result: fail ");
                        return CheckResult.Fail;
                    }
                    Logger.Debug("Password Age: check result: pass ");
                    return CheckResult.Pass;


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.LogException(ex, "Error in PasswordAge->Check()");
                    return CheckResult.Exception;
                }
            }
}
public static bool isCurrentUserLocalUser()
{
    return Environment.MachineName == Environment.UserDomainName;
}
```

Just for clarification, it's not my code so I'm not completely sure what the code owner did.

---

I'm seeing that there are no responses. I will ask different question.
Is there any option to obtain password age or password last set values without be depend on network connection? Is it possible to check it locally? 
I know this value also exists under "Local security policy" but I didn't find how to get it by code.

Comment: Are you saying you're getting the exception whilst running the code on a workstation on the WiFi guest network?  Are you running with a local user account or a domain account?

Comment: yes exactly. I'm running with domain account.

Comment: Are you sure the laptop can see the domain?  How have you proved this?

Comment: I'm not sure. In other networks with same laptop it works. Is it says something? Is it possible that it's a network settings? maybe this guest network blocks the access to the AD?

Comment: By guest WiFi, do you mean a WiFi network provided for your guests to use to access the internet whilst they're in your office?  If that's so, it probably won't have access to your AD.  Your network team should be able to confirm.

Comment: yes I mean to a WiFi network provided for guests. I read that it can be checked through Local password policy so I want to find a way to check this offline when I can't connect to my AD

Comment: Hmmmm.  I haven't come across anything that would help.  Where did you read that?